# How to provide a title with spaces on an axis in azure log analytics?

Tags: azure, analytics

Consider the following query:

```
Perf
| where CounterName == '% Processor Time'
| project TimeGenerated, CounterValue
| render timechart
```

It yields something like this:

[image]

I would like it to display '% Processor Time' instead of CounterValue. However, I cannot use `project_rename`, since the desired title contains spaces. So, how do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will do what you want:

```
Perf
| where CounterName == '% Processor Time'
| project TimeGenerated, ['% Processor Time']=CounterValue 
| render timechart
```